# Error de indentación en Python

Tags: python

Quería un poco de ayuda en este código en el que me estaba apoyando para aprender Python, pero soy incapaz de solventar el error de indentación que me presenta.

¿Algún alma altruista puede ayudarme? Me serviría de mucho.

Un saludo

```py
import random
def ahorcado():

 listaPalabras = ("zapato", "bisagra", "volante", "bordillo", "ventilador")
 letrasValidas = "abcdefghijklmnñopqrstuvwxyz"
 palabra = random.choice(listaPalabras)
 guessmade = ''

 while len(palabra) > 0:
     main = ''
     turnos = 10

     for letra in palabra:
         if letra in guessmade:
             main = main + letra
         else:
             main = main + "_" + " "
     if main == palabra:
         print(main)
         print("Felicidades! Has adivinado mi palabra")
         break

     print("Cual va a ser tu letra?: ", main)
     letra = input()

     if letra in letrasValidas:
         guessmade = guessmade + letra
     else:
         print ("Introduce un caracter válido")
         letra = input()

     if letra not in palabra:
         turnos = turnos - 1
         print("Lo siento, esa letra no esta en mi palabra")
         print("Turnos restantes: ", turnos)
         if turnos == 0: break

print("Hola! Bienvenido al ahorcado! Adivina mi palabra")
print("Tienes 10 intentos")
ahorcado()

C:\Users\Desktop\Python>py Ahorcado.py
File "Ahorcado.py", line 11
 main = ''
         ^
TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation
```

El error de indentación de este tipo también se presenta en otros códigos que tengo de Python pero que soy incapaz de resolver como este.

Supongo que será una característica del lenguaje que no llego a comprender (mas allá de la fuerte indentación que tiene)

Comment: En principio no parece que tengas ningún error de indentación, lo que te está diciendo es que has mezclado el uso de tabulaciones y de espacios. con que no los mezcles debería funcionar (si el resto del código está bien)

Comment: Podrías decir en que IDE programas o como estás haciendo la indentacion? puede ser un problema de la cantidad de espacios que proporcione un TAB?

Answer (score 5):

tu problema se debe a que has usado ambas formas de indentación (espacio y tabulador) en el mismo código, elige una u otra y úsala en todas las lineas.

Answer (score 4):

Si usas Linux, puedes intentar tener mas información con este comando:

```
grep -C 7 "main = ''" cod.py | tr ' \t' '.*'
```

Esto transformará los espacios en puntos y las tabulaciones en asteriscos. Así podrás revisar cuál es la inconsistencia.

Esta es la salida del comando cuando lo uso con tu código:

```
$ grep -C 7 "main = ''" cod.py | tr ' \t' '.*'

*
....listaPalabras.=.("zapato",."bisagra",."volante",."bordillo",."ventilador")
....letrasValidas.=."abcdefghijklmnñopqrstuvwxyz"
....palabra.=.random.choice(listaPalabras)
....guessmade.=.''
....
....while.len(palabra).>.0:
**main.=.''
**turnos.=.10

**for.letra.in.palabra:
***if.letra.in.guessmade:
**.**main.=.main.+.letra
**.*else:
**.**main.=.main.+."_".+."."
```

Como puedes ver, hay una gran mezcla de espacios (puntos) y tabulaciones (asteriscos).

Comment: estas asumiendo que el op usa linux lo cual no es seguro

Answer (score 2):

Te esta diciendo que en la misma linea has usado espacios y tabulaciones para indentar.

La mayoría de ides y editores tienes opciones para arreglar esto, generalmente bajo los menús "editar" o "formato", algunos en "código"

También es bueno que mires las opciones, suele haber una que convierte tabulaciones en espacios a la hora de ponerlos.
te pongo algunos por orden alfabético, hay muchos mas.

Ejemplos de ides: eclipse, netbeans, pycharm, spider, visual studio

Ejemplos de editores: atom, notepad++, sublime text